# Where to Find a UI example for Settings WebPage

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have a Web Page where there are list of Settings provided to the end user, I am displaying these functionalities through simple divs, but my UI design looks very poor...I am not so good with CSS styling.Can anybody refer any good example that I can use to design my Settings WebPage ?? thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually find lists like these to be fairly inspiring ->

> http://www.ourtuts.com/34-outstanding-admin-panels-for-your-web-applications/

I would also do common google searches for 'Administration themes', 'Administration Panels', and combinations of those using the words like design, structures, examples, templates, etc.

Comment: Really nice collection of examples for admin page...thanks a lot for the link :)